# Can't delete product combinations on 1.7.4.3

Tags: php, apache, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have imported the products with the "Import" native function of Prestashop.

Than I imported the combinations, and it works for most products.

**The problem now is that I can't delete combinations in back office. 
Why?**

```
**Prestashop version:** 1.7.4.3

**Informazioni sul server** Linux #1 SMP Thu Jan 25 20:13:58 UTC 2018 x86_64

**Versione software del server:** CentOS WebPanel: Protected by Mod Security

**Versione di PHP:** 7.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it, by disabling the caches, and I have enabled the force compilation of templates and add this code to your .htaccess

```
<RequireAny>
Require method DELETE GET POST PUT OPTIONS
</RequireAny>

<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

There is the fix: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/10198

Answer (score 0):

Please use this for resolving the issue:

Go in the Backoffice Traffic and SEO/ SEO urls and generate all options by clicking the safe button.